# Probability of same number of successes at least 1/2 the time

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n,Y_1\dots,Y_n$ all be i.i.d. Bernouli random variables with success probability $p$.

Let $S$ be the set of $s \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ where $\sum_{i=1}^s X_i = \sum_{i=1}^s Y_i$. Is there a name for the distribution $|S|$? For fixed $p$ as $n\to \infty$, I am wondering if$$\Bbb{P}(|S| \ge n/2) = \exp(-\Omega(n)).$$

I am also interested in answers to these questions for the related model where we condition on $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i = pn$.

Edit: I realize that letting $Z_i = X_i-Y_i$, and defining $W_0 = 0$, $W_t = Z_t + W_{t-1}$, that $S = \{t: W_t = 0 \}$. Thus, I guess the first problem is about an unbiased lazy random walk on $\Bbb{Z}$ that has a probability of $1-2p+2p^2$ of not moving. I still don't know how to calculate the probability in the equation though, or how this translates to the related model.

Comment: Intuitively, it seems like the probability would be smallest when $p=\frac12$, so it might be best to start with that case, which is likely to be the easiest.

Comment: When $p=\frac12$ there is a nice symmetry which means that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^s X_i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^s Y_i$ has the same probability as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^s X_i + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i =s$ and as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2s} X_i =s$, which is ${2s \choose s} 4^{-s}$ and I think for large $s$ is about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi s}}$, suggesting $E[|S|]$ might be about $2\sqrt{\frac n\pi}-1$ .  But this may not help.